# Local LAMP server slow on mobile devices

Tags: raspbian, dhcp, apache-httpd, mysql

I set a local lamp server at my raspberry 2 B. I uploaded a HD media file in it is working well when I browse I can watch video well. My problem is I am connecting to raspi by wireless and it is superfast at laptop but when i tried to connect from mobile phone (iphone+safari) it is super slow. I tried it with andorid+chrome it is better but you can call it slow again. Which part of the server (DHCP+Apache+Mysql+Wordpress) could be the problem ?

Comment: How do the ping times between laptop/android/iphone compare?

Comment: from laptop 1ms

Comment: Your mobile phone never directly connects to the pi. It must go through your router so if your ping time from your laptop is 1ms the problem is likely to be on the client side with your android device. Can you please elaborate on what "superslow" means by placing benchmarks here. Also please elaborate on where you believe that the problem is occurring as the full lamp stack plus your network connection is too vague for me to be able to offer any non generic advice. Finally if you could include which parts of the site lag while loading(the html, css file, images, video) that would be helpful.